# Unable to login to SQL Server + SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i am not able to login with sql server authentication,

what i tried is :

and while i setup, i did following user :

please anybody help , what's the way to open sql server authentication

this is what i get from log :

Comment: The password is for `sa`.

Comment: The "Administrator" account you are using is the local windows account which is different from "sa" (System Administrator) account (for Sql server). Thats the one you are setting password for. Thats the one you should be using for logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the setup wizard has the text...

> Specify the password for the SQL Server system administrator (sa) account

...is because it's for the `sa` account.

[image]

The three accounts you've added as administrators will work just fine with Windows Authentication.

Comment: what is the password for : sa?

Comment: @patel - Same one you used while setting it up

Comment: @patel: The one you set in the dialog that **asked you to provide a password for sa**, of course.

Comment: Ok, let me try and see event logs!

Comment: @patel - I doubt event logs contain that sensitive info. Why dont you use windows authentication with your login?

Comment: the same error i got here : http://s15.postimg.org/lkzas5rh7/Screenshot_121.png

Comment: very strange, i am able to login with NEW create username and password :(